# Change phpMyAdmin's path for WampServer

Tags: wampserver

I'm currently accessing my phpMyAdmin this way with wampserver:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
```

Is there any way I could change the path to anything I want, say:

```
http://127.0.0.1/adm123/
```

This would also make `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`unavailable.

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on your current setup, so _why_ that application is published under that URL. Different options exist. Please post your current configuration of the http host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can copy your phpmyadmin folder which is in the following file path to a desired place

```
C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.5.2
```

then past it where you want. After that change the phpmyadmin.conf file which is in the following path

```
C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me! I didn't even have to move phpmyadmin, just opening the conf file and changing the "Alias" line did it. Once again, thank you so much, I'm surprised it was this easy. :)